# Best to use join or append?

Tags: python, join, append

Currently I have this code:

```
with open(w_file, 'r') as file_r:
    for line in file_r:
        if len(line) > 0:
          spLine = line.split()
          if(spLine[0] == operandID and spLine[1] == bitID
             and spLine[3] == sInstID and spLine[4] == opcodeID):
              spLine[-2]='1'
              line = ' '.join(spLine)  # I need to add a new line into
                                       # "line" after join all the spLine
          lines.append(line)
          print line
with open(w_file, 'w') as file_w:
    for line in lines:
       file_w.write(line)
```

The output:

```
1 60 14039 470 13 0 28
1 60 14039 470 13 0 28
0 60 14039 470 13 1 281 60 14039 470 13 0 28  # I want to separate these two
1 60 14039 470 13 0 28                        # lines, this wrong situation
                                              # only happens when I found
                                              # the target line which
                                              # satisfies the if statement.
```

Comment: You cannot use append with a string. Just simple add a newline after join using `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `+ "\n"` to the end, like this.

```
line = ' '.join(spLine) + "\n"
```

This will add a new line after the joining.

Comment: Thank You so Much! I do not even know I can do this

Comment: Your welcome. If you want more on python strings look here, [Python Strings Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)